404 for All API Routes After Deploying Laravel with React (Vite) – / API Route Works Fine
Issue:
After deploying my Laravel project with a React front-end (using Vite), I encounter a 404 error for all API routes, except the root / route which correctly returns the login page (200 status). However, when I try to hit any API endpoints (e.g., login submission, registration, etc.), I get a 404 error.
Details:

Laravel version: [^11.9]
Server: [Apache]

Steps I've taken so far:
The / route works fine and returns the login component, but all other API routes return 404 errors.
I have tested the APIs using Postman, and all of them return a 404 error, except the / route.
I have checked my web.php and api.php routes and everything seems correct. Here's the relevant parts:
web.php:
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AboutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AccueilController;
///......

Route::get('/contacts', [ContactController::class, 'getAll']);
Route::put('/contacts/{id}', action: [ContactController::class, 'update']);


Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Auth/Login');
})->name('login');


Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])- 
 >name('profile.update');
Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])- 
 >name('profile.destroy');
});


Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('register');

Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('login');

Route::post('loginSubmit', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
    ->name('loginSubmit');

Route::get('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('password.request');

Route::post('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
    ->name('password.email');

Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('password.reset');

Route::post('reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
    ->name('password.store');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
Route::get('verify-email', EmailVerificationPromptController::class)
    ->name('verification.notice');

Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', VerifyEmailController::class)
    ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
    ->name('verification.verify');

Route::post('email/verification-notification', 
[EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware('throttle:6,1')
    ->name('verification.send');

Route::get('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('password.confirm');

Route::post('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store']);

Route::put('password', [PasswordController::class, 'update'])- 
 >name('password.update');

Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
    ->name('logout');
});

api.php:
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AboutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AccueilController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//......


// Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//     return $request->user();
// })->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::middleware('api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

// Define the API route for sending contact messages
Route::post('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'sendContactEmail']);


Route::get('/contacts', [ContactController::class, 'getAll']);
Route::put('/contacts/{id}', [ContactController::class, 'update']);
Route::post('/contacts', [ContactController::class, 'create']);

Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'getAll']);
Route::put('/about/{id}', [AboutController::class, 'update']);
Route::post('/about', [AboutController::class, 'create']);

Route::get('/accueil', [AccueilController::class, 'getAll']);
Route::put('/accueil/{id}', [AccueilController::class, 'update']);
Route::post('/accueil', [AccueilController::class, 'create']);

Route::get('/message', [MessagesController::class, 'getAll']);
Route::put('/message/{id}', [MessagesController::class, 'update']);
Route::post('/message', [MessagesController::class, 'create']);

Route::get('/products', [ProductsController::class, 'getAll']);
Route::put('/products/{id}', [ProductsController::class, 'update']);
Route::post('/products', [ProductsController::class, 'create']);



I tried debugging by inspecting the source of the page. In the page source (mySubdomain.ma/index), I found the following Ziggy configuration:
const Ziggy = {
    "url": "http:\/\/mySubdomain.ma",
    "port": null,
    "defaults": {},
    "routes": {
        "sanctum.csrf-cookie": { "uri": "sanctum\/csrf-cookie", "methods": ["GET", "HEAD"] },
        "login": { "uri": "login", "methods": ["GET", "HEAD"] },
        "dashboard": { "uri": "dashboard", "methods": ["GET", "HEAD"] },
        // more routes here...
    }
};

What I've tried to resolve:
I checked the .htaccess file for the correct rewrite rules (since I'm using Apache), but no changes fixed the issue.
I disabled CSRF protection for testing purposes, but the problem persists.
I ensured that the API routes are correctly defined in api.php and the correct domain/subdomain is being used for the API requests.
Question:
Why does the '/' route (login page) work fine but all other API routes return 404 errors?
Could this be related to the Ziggy configuration for the API requests?
How can I fix the routing issue so that all API routes work correctly after deployment?
Any help or guidance on resolving this would be appreciated!

You cleared the caches and such php artisan cache:clear and routes:clear? Also, check for the "hot" file in the public directory and remove it if it is there. Other than that, no idea on what might be wrong. If you have console access, you can also double check with php artisan route:list --path=api if the routes are really there.
